# Tasks targeted at dynamic backend fail frequently, silently

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I had converted some tasks to run on a dynamic backend.

The tasks are failing silently [no logged error, no retry, nothing] ~20% of the time (min:10%, max:60%, sample:large, long term).  Switching the task away from the backend restores retries and gets the failure rate back to ~0%.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting it to a backend exacerbated the problem but wasn't the problem.

I had specified a `task_retry_limit` and the queue was a push queue.  With a backend the number of instances is specified.  (I believe you can replicate this issue on the frontend by ramping up requests rapidly, to a big number).

Tasks were failing `503: Instance Unavailable` until they hit the `task_retry_limit`.  This is visible temporarily in Task Queues, but will not show up in Logs.

I should be using pull queues.  Even if my use case was stupid I'd probably +1 a task dying due to multiple `503: Instance Unavailable` logging something so it doesn't appear like a phantom task.

Answer (score 0):

Which runtime are you using on the backend?
Try running the backend for a bit without dynamic set to true and exercise the failing component.

On my project, I have seen tasks that target a static backend disappear on occasion, but no where near the rate you are seeing.