# Google Cloud SQL Dropping Writes

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I'm currently using Goole App Engine w/ Google Cloud SQL & SQLAlchemy. I'm uploading and processing a lot of data and using TaskQueues to write this data to Google Cloud SQL.

Locally everything looks fine and all of the data successfully is written to the database. However, when uploading to Google Cloud SQL on AppEngine a few of the writes (about 1-2%) don't make it.

There are no errors in the logs. I am trying to figure possible scenarios / where this issue might be coming from.

Comment: Perhaps some missing commits?  Autocommit mode should fix that but I'm personally not sure if it's 100% reliable (not that I have any specific reason to suspect it isn't, just musing out loud).  Are you calling commit on every write?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, it turns out that tasks in the TaskQueue were unable to get the resource to run ([Tasks targeted at dynamic backend fail frequently, silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067361/tasks-targeted-at-dynamic-backend-fail-frequently-silently)). The tasks were failing silently and explained the lost writes.

Answer (score -1):

your cloud sql must not be on always ON basis. it takes time to switch it on while an instance comes, so always put sql on full time ON mode